# Mgf of distribution to prove sample variance is equal to expectation of sample variance

Tags: probability, statistics

If X1,X2,...,Xn ∼ iid N(μ,σ2) and S2 is the sample variance, and E(S2) = σ2. Let Y = (n − 1)S2/σ2. Using the mgf of Y , how can you find the expected value of Y and conclude that E(S2) = σ2. What does the mgf of Y look like? How should I start the proof as well?

Comment: I know how to get the mgf of Y, but how do I relate that to the expected value of Y, and in doing so, show E(S^2)= σ^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you know how to get the moment-generating function of $Y$, I'll start from there. We have, for the moment-generating function:
$$M_Y(t) = (1-2t)^{-(n-1)/2}$$
Now, remember that $M_Y(t) = \Bbb E[e^{tY}]$, so that $\partial_t M_Y(0) = \Bbb E[Y]$. The derivative is:
$$\partial_t M_Y(t) = (n-1)(1-2t)^{-(n-1)/2}$$
So we know that
$$\Bbb E[Y] = n-1$$
But $\Bbb E[Y] = \frac{n-1}{\sigma^2}\Bbb E[S^2]$, so
$$\frac{n-1}{\sigma^2}\Bbb E[S^2] = n-1 \Longrightarrow \Bbb E[S^2] = \sigma^2$$
as desired!

Comment: @a.nas $n-1$ is a constant and $\sigma^2$ is a constant parameter, so they can be safely pulled out of the expectation operator $\Bbb E[\cdot]$. Remember that $\Bbb E[\cdot]$ is a linear operator!